# Change String date (DD.MM.YY) to Dateformat(YYYY-MM-DD) in excel

Tags: string, excel, date, vba

I have nearly 2,00,000 records of data in my excel sheet and I have Date columns as a string like this (dd.mm.yy) I have to convert it into dateformat of (YYYY-MM-DD) .

I tried this -

For the example date string, 1.11.11 , I tried to replace .11 with .2011 but it will also change the month to 1.2011.2011 and my sheet has huge records from 2010 to 2016 .

> Example - My cell has this 1.11.11 and i want to convert it to 2011-01-01 (YYYY-MM-DD)

Please help !
Thank you.

Comment: Aside: Make sure you understand Excel's y2k algorithm.  Two-digit years >= 30 are considered to be in the 1900s.  If you want something different, you'll need to code that yourself.

Comment: i don't have any records past 17 ,so no issues .Thanks ! Matt Johnson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this to change it to a true date:

```
=DATE(2000+SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,2),".",""),SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,2),".",""),SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,2),".",""))
```

Then format the output to your desired: `YYYY-MM-DD`

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRm]

---

To do it in place one would need vba.

Select your date cells and run this code.

```
Sub datechange()
Dim rng As Range
Dim str() As String

For Each rng In Selection
    str = Split(rng.Value, ".")
    rng.Value = DateSerial(2000 + str(2), str(1), str(0))
Next rng
Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"

End Sub
```

Comment: This works but how to apply this on whole sheet at once ? I cannot manually do it for 2lakh data !

Comment: @Savan I have given you the backbone on which you can build.  As I stated earlier, this is not a code for me site.  try and figure out how to replace `Selection` with the ranges that have your dates.  If you get stuck come back with your attempts and post a new question with that code stating where the problem is and ask a specific question.

Comment: Yes surely ! ill try and comeback @Scott Craner

Comment: How can i add a condition to this script of doing nothing if the cell is empty ? @Scott Craner

Comment: New question gets new post.

Comment: I got the solution .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values start in A1 AND if they are all truly in the DD.MM.YY (with zeroes (04, 06, etc...)

```
="20"&RIGHT(A1,2)&"-"&MID(A1,4,1)&"-"&LEFT(A1,2)
```

Comment: It should be ** ="20"&RIGHT(A1,2)&"-"&MID(A1,4,1)&"-"&LEFT(A1,2)** you should have 1 instead of 2 in mid section ,But my question is how can i apply this on whole file ??

Comment: Well, if the date is in DD-MM-YY, why would mid be 1?
Regardless, I think Scott's answer above is best.

Comment: @Savan You cannot do that with formula, it will need to be vba.

Comment: How can i do that ,im not familar with vba.Instead i was thinking of taking it to database and chaning their ,I can do this with query if i get it in (dd.mm.yyyy) format @ScottCraner

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow formula :

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","/"),"YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Comment: This will work only if the local settings is `dd/mm/yyyy` you will also need to change the text to a number using either `DATEVALUE`, `VALUE` or `--`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select convert(varchar,convert(datetime,'26-July-2018'),105)
```